# How to properly page data from SQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, react-redux

I wanted to ask a question on how to properly page data from MySQL database. In simple terms I have a database with a decent bit of records, this specific table I am trying to paginate has 400-500 rows. What I did want to ask what is the best way, in terms of speed and memory cost of paging this data?

The current solution and controller I have:

```
[HttpGet("{startIndex}")]
public IEnumerable < ServerList > Get(int startIndex) {
    Console.WriteLine(startIndex);
    List < ServerList > serverList = new List < ServerList > ();
    string constr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("IKekwBotWebAppContext");
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr)) {
        string query = "SELECT `id`, `server_id`, `server_number`, `server_name`, `addr`, `tribe`, `relation`, `server-info` FROM `servers` WHERE id > " + startIndex + " ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 15";
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query)) {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using(MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (sdr.Read()) {
                    serverList.Add(new ServerList {
                        Id = int.Parse(sdr.GetString(0)),
                        Server_id = int.Parse(sdr.GetString(1)),
                        Server_number = sdr.GetString(2),
                        Server_name = sdr.GetString(3),
                        Server_address = sdr.GetString(4),
                        Server_tribe = sdr.GetString(5),
                        Server_relation = sdr.GetString(6),
                        Server_Info = sdr.GetString(7)
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return serverList;
}
```

With combination of React and Redux with two buttons I pass the index to the controller which returns the data, however, sometimes, the data returned is duplicated or the same even when it should be the next page.

React code (a small part of it)

```js
private renderServerListTable() {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Server Number</th>
                        <th>Server Name</th>
                        <th>Server Address</th>
                        <th>Server Tribe</th>
                        <th>Server Relation</th>
                        <th>Server Info</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.serverLists.map((server: ServerListStore.ServerList) =>
                        <tr key={server.server_id}>
                            <td>{server.server_number}</td>
                            <td>{server.server_name}</td>
                            <td>{server.server_address}</td>
                            <td>{server.server_tribe}</td>
                            <td>{server.server_relation}</td>
                            <td>{server.server_Info}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

    private renderPagination() {
        const prevStartDateIndex = (this.props.startDateIndex || 0) - 15;
        const nextStartDateIndex = (this.props.startDateIndex || 0) + 15;

        return (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <Link className='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm' to={`/server-list/${prevStartDateIndex}`}>Previous</Link>
                {this.props.isLoading && <span>Loading...</span>}
                <Link className='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm' to={`/server-list/${nextStartDateIndex}`}>Next</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Any suggestions what would be a more efficient or more reliable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to this problem is, if your `id` value has an index, very close to ideal.

The query pattern

```
SELECT stuff 
  FROM table
 WHERE indexedValue > startIndex 
 ORDER BY indexedValue
 LIMIT 10
```

is about as efficient a paginating query as it can get.  It's certainly  more efficient than   `...ORDER BY indexedValue LIMIT 10 OFFSET startIndex`.

Pagination can be trickier if you have a way to sort on an arbitrary column.

Answer (score -1):

I would have removed the `WHERE` clause in favor of `OFFSET` and `FETCH` capabilities to implement pagination, hence my query would have become something similar to:

```
string query = "SELECT `id`, `server_id`, `server_number`, `server_name`, `addr`, `tribe`, `relation`, `server-info` FROM `servers` ORDER BY `id` OFFSET" + startIndex + " ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS;
```

But in favor of performance, seeking on a Unique Column does look like a better approach. [My understanding is based on the following link](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/) .

The Cached page boundaries can be a solution as well:

[Cached Page Boundries](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/18/faster-sql-pagination-with-keysets-continued/)

Comment: This might be worth reading. In my experience it's exactly right. https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: Note that your query is not MySQL